# Why my status bar is hiding when I zooming in my text editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text-editor

#### When I increase the font size of Text widget my status bar is hiding why?

The code of Text widget:

```
    self.text_frame = Frame(self,borderwidth=0)
    self.text_frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
    self.font = Font(size=10)
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.text_frame)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    self.Text_input = Text(self.text_frame, yscrollcommand = 
    self.scrollbar.set,undo=True,font=self.font,borderwidth=0)
    self.Text_input.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.Text_input.yview)
```

The code of statusbar:

```
            self.statusbar_frame = Frame(self,borderwidth=1,relief=SUNKEN)
            self.statusbar_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X,)
            self.statusvar = StringVar()
            self.statusvar.set("Ready ")
            self.sbar = Label(self.statusbar_frame, textvariable=self.statusvar, anchor="w",borderwidth=0)
            self.sbar.pack(side=LEFT)
            self.inlabel = StringVar()
            self.u_label = Label(self.statusbar_frame,text="UTF-8", anchor="w",borderwidth=0)
            self.u_label.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=7)
            self.w_label = Label(self.statusbar_frame,text=f"{system()}(CRLF)", anchor="w",borderwidth=0)
            self.w_label.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=7)            
            self.fontsize_label = Label(self.statusbar_frame,text=f"100%", anchor="w",borderwidth=0)
            self.fontsize_label.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=7)
            self.curosor_label = Label(self.statusbar_frame,textvariable=self.inlabel, anchor="w",borderwidth=0)
            self.curosor_label.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=7)
```

Error:
In normal size-
[image: in normal size]

In 140% zoom
[image: in 140% zoom]

After 140% zoom-
[image: Error]

Comment: First pack the status bar, then the `Text` widget.

Comment: Thank you so much, you answer is absolutely correct

Answer (score 1):

It is because the size of the text widget changes when you change the font. It appears you've also forced the size of the window to be a specific size. When the text widget grows, there is no longer enough room in the window to fit all widgets at their preferred size.

When that happens, tkinter must start shrinking widgets. The packer does this in the reverse order that things were packed (or more precisely, it allocates space starting with the first widget, so the packer runs out of space by the time it gets to the last widget). You almost certainly packed the text widget first and then the statusbar, so `pack` runs out of space before it gets to the statusbar.

The solution is pretty simple: pack the statusbar before packing the text widget so that it gets all of the space it needs. With the text widget being packed last, it is the one that will be shrunk if the packer needs to reduce the size of the widgets so that they will fit on the screen.